# + is unavailable: Please use explicit type conversions or Strideable methods for mixed-type arithmetics

Tags: swift, swift4

I'm trying to learn Swift and am looking at an old Generic example that worked in Swift 2

```
func increment<T: Strideable>(number: T) -> T {
    return number + 1
}
```

Now in Swift 4 it complains

```
'+' is unavailable: Please use explicit type conversions or Strideable methods for mixed-type arithmetics
```

Why am I getting this error and what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Swift is extremely stupid in term of dynamic typing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Rather than using the `+` operator, you can simply use `Strideable.advanced(by:)`.

```
func increment<T: Strideable>(number: T) -> T {
    return number.advanced(by: 1)
}

increment(number: 2) //returns 3
increment(number: 2.5) //returns 3.5
```

Comment: You mean, "Rather than simply using the `+` operator, you now have to use `Strideable.advanced(by:)`".

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 4 use

.advanced(by: 1)

for this refer URl:- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/strideable